# Casting vector<T1>* to vector<T2>* where sizeof(T1) != sizeof(T2)

Tags: c++

I would like to cast a `vector<uint8_t>&` of binary data to a `vector<int16_t>&` preferably without copying any data. Running the code below (compiled with gcc 9.4.0) I find that the size of `data16` is 3. Is casting vector pointers with types of different sizes safe or does it produce undefined behaviour?

````
#include <cinttypes>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data8 = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    std::vector<int16_t>& data16 = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int16_t>*>(&data8);
    std::cout << data16.size() << std::endl;
}```
````

Comment: You can't do it. You'll get UB even if types have the same size.

Comment: It is not safe if they have the same size either. Use of any such cast, even `std::vector<char>` to `std::vector<unsigned char>`, has undefined behavior.

Comment: Since a vector is guaranteed to be continuous, you can take a T1*. Now whether T1* can be safely converted to T2* is another issue. In case of byte <-> short then you have 2 bytes creating 1 word. However converting this to a vector<int16_t> is not a good idea - you can't "attach" a vector to an array.